# Bind value of selected dropdown value from one autocomplete field to another with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, material-design, angular-material

With the help of the official Angular-Material Docs [found here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete), I have managed to add three autocomplete fields next to each other. However, I would like to bind the value selected from the **first dropdown field** to be automatically selected on the **third dropdown field** too.

What would be the best approach to binding the first autocomplete value to the third but *NOT* vice-versa?

The autocomplete of all three fields looks like this but each of them are wrapped in their own separate controllers:

```
<form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
    <md-autocomplete
        ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled"
        md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
        md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
        md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
        md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
        md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
        md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
        md-item-text="item.display"
        md-min-length="1"
        md-floating-label="Final">
        <md-item-template>
            <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
        </md-item-template>
        <md-not-found>
            No items matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
        </md-not-found>
    </md-autocomplete>
</form>
```

And the JS which I copied from the example Docs:

```
app.controller('abcCtrl', abcCtrls);
    function abcCtrls ($timeout, $q, $log) {
        var self = this;
        self.simulateQuery = false;
        self.isDisabled    = false;
        // list of `state` value/display objects
        self.states        = loadAll();
        self.querySearch   = querySearch;
        self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
        self.searchTextChange   = searchTextChange;
        self.newState = newState;
        function newState(state) {
          alert("Sorry! You'll need to create a Constituion for " + state + " first!");
        }
        // ******************************
        // Internal methods
        // ******************************
        /**
         * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
         * remote dataservice call.
         */
        function querySearch (query) {
          var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.states,
              deferred;
          if (self.simulateQuery) {
            deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve( results ); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
            return deferred.promise;
          } else {
            return results;
          }
        }
        function searchTextChange(text) {
          $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
        }
        function selectedItemChange(item) {
          $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
        }
        /**
         * Build `states` list of key/value pairs
         */
        function loadAll() {
          var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
                  Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
                  Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
                  Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
                  North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
                  South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
                  Wisconsin, Wyoming';
          return allStates.split(/, +/g).map( function (state) {
            return {
              value: state.toLowerCase(),
              display: state
            };
          });
        }
        /**
         * Create filter function for a query string
         */
        function createFilterFor(query) {
          var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
          return function filterFn(state) {
            return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> `md-selected-item-change` is an expression to be run each time a new item is selected
>
> So in your function `selectedItemChange`, set the model which represents third `autocomplete`field.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="abcCtrl as ctrl">
    <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
        <md-autocomplete ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled" md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)" md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" md-min-length="1" md-floating-label="Final">
            <md-item-template><span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>

            </md-item-template>
            <md-not-found>No items matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.</md-not-found>
        </md-autocomplete>
        <md-autocomplete ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled" md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem2" md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText2)" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText2" md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText2)" md-item-text="item.display" md-min-length="1" md-floating-label="Final">
            <md-item-template><span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>

            </md-item-template>
            <md-not-found>No items matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.</md-not-found>
        </md-autocomplete>
        <md-autocomplete ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled" md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem3" md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText3)" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText3" md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText3)" md-item-text="item.display" md-min-length="1" md-floating-label="Final">
            <md-item-template><span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText3" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>

            </md-item-template>
            <md-not-found>No items matching "{{ctrl.searchText3}}" were found.</md-not-found>
        </md-autocomplete>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('abcCtrl', abcCtrls);

function abcCtrls($timeout, $q, $log) {
    var self = this;
    self.simulateQuery = false;
    self.isDisabled = false;
    // list of `state` value/display objects
    self.states = loadAll();
    self.querySearch = querySearch;
    self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
    self.searchTextChange = searchTextChange;
    self.newState = newState;

    function newState(state) {
        alert("Sorry! You'll need to create a Constituion for " + state + " first!");
    }

    // ******************************
    // Internal methods
    // ******************************
    /**
     * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
     * remote dataservice call.
     */
    function querySearch(query) {
        var results = query ? self.states.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : self.states,
                deferred;
        if (self.simulateQuery) {
            deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                deferred.resolve(results);
            }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
            return deferred.promise;
        } else {
            return results;
        }
    }

    function searchTextChange(text) {
        $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
    }

    function selectedItemChange(item) {
        self.selectedItem3 = item;
        $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
    }

    /**
     * Build `states` list of key/value pairs
     */
    function loadAll() {
        var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
              Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
              Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
              Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
              North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
              South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
              Wisconsin, Wyoming';
        return allStates.split(/, +/g).map(function (state) {
            return {
                value: state.toLowerCase(),
                display: state
            };
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create filter function for a query string
     */
    function createFilterFor(query) {
        var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
        return function filterFn(state) {
            return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: "So in your function `selected-Item-Change`, set the model which represents third `autocomplete` field" So I should add the above function below or above the current js that I copied Rayon?

Comment: Btw, I'm just starting to learn angularJs so please don't mind the noob questions.

Comment: Just set the value of third element `model` i.e. `selectedItem`

Comment: So this `md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"` will be `md-selected-item-change="newState"` or?

Comment: See `ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)` is a method which is being called and it has argument as selected value. Just set this value as third element model. Do not complicate things...

Comment: So I edited the `md-selected-item-change` of third field to `md-selected-item-change="octrl.selectedItemChange(item)"` where `octrl` is from the first field's ng-controller i.e. `ng-controller="firstField as octrl"` but it's not working Rayon :( What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I copied your code and gave the second field searchText2 instead of 3 but now all three are linked to each other where if you change one, the other two are changed as well. I just want the third to copy the first but I'm not sure if I'm missing some codes or something.